# Praying salah in a Christian household

Tags: salat, non-muslim

Asalamu Alaykum,
So for the next month and a half I’ll be staying at my aunts house. My mom side of the family are all Christians. And i was just wondering if I’m able to pray in a Christian household and if my prayer will be accepted since every inch of the house is filled with jesus posters and crosses & there isn’t really any other rooms to pray in. Please let me know as I’m unsure

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model I recommend you to take the [tour] and check our [help]. As to your question this sounds weird and exaggerated I've never seen such a Christian household, if it exists you may have a bedroom or a place for your own you may there find a refuge or create one.

Comment: You can get a rug and pray outside, like in a yard or something.

Comment: At work I pray with Sunni brothers in a Church. Not sure why you can't pray at their home. Do you think when you enter a Muslim's house everything in their mind about Allah is correct 100%? If that was the case then they would all be infallible Muslims...

Answer (score -2):

Your Question ...*i was just wondering if I’m able to pray in a Christian household* ...

Yes! you can, as long as the place is "Clean / Paak" (Which is obligatory).

You should learn the **Thirteen (13) Obligation** to pray Salah (some say its is 12). There is no need to worry about the environment. May Allah accept your prayers, Ameen!. Wallah Alam.

General Requirements:

1. Purification of Place
2. Purification of Body
3. Purification of Clothes
4. Covering
5. Facing the Qiblah
6. Time
7. Niyyah (Intention)

Above are general requirements before praying. You can contact Ulama/ Imam Masjid for more details. 
http://www.myreligionislam.com/detail.asp?Aid=6117